# How do I calculate the prediction interval for a multilevel meta-analysis?

Tags: r, prediction, metafor

I am conducting a three-level meta-analysis on experimental data using the `rma.mv()` function from the `metafor` package. Here's an example code for the model fit:

```
model <- metafor::rma.mv(yi,                     
                         V,                                
                         slab = author,                
                         data = data,                   
                         random = ~ 1 | author/effect_size, 
                         test = "t",                       
                         method = "REML")
```

Unfortunately, the results do not include a prediction interval. In the `meta` package, the `metagen()` function has gives you the prediction interval on top of pooled estimate and confidence intervals, if you specify the argument `prediction = TRUE`. For an example, see here: https://bookdown.org/MathiasHarrer/Doing_Meta_Analysis_in_R/heterogeneity.html?q=prediction%20interval#het-R. Here's an excerpt from example results including the prediction interval:

```
## Number of studies combined: k = 18
## 
##                         SMD            95%-CI    t  p-value
## Random effects model 0.5771 [ 0.3782; 0.7760] 6.12 < 0.0001     # Pooled effect estimate
## Prediction interval         [-0.0619; 1.2162]                   # Prediction Interval
## 
## Quantifying heterogeneity:
##  tau^2 = 0.0820 [0.0295; 0.3533]; tau = 0.2863 [0.1717; 0.5944];
##  I^2 = 62.6% [37.9%; 77.5%]; H = 1.64 [1.27; 2.11]
## 
## Test of heterogeneity:
##      Q d.f. p-value
##  45.50   17  0.0002
```

Is there a way to calculate the prediction interval using the `rma.mv()` function from `metafor`? If not, is there another way of calculating it for the case of a three-level random-effects model meta-analysis?

Comment: Use `predict(model)`.

Comment: All right, thank you! Just what was needed.